# How to make a responsive div box that changes size when changing window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So I want the width and height of my div box to grow/shrink in size when a user resizes the webpage. I want the window size and box size to change simultaneously, so the box stretches when the window stretches. Is there a way to do this solely in css?

here is what i have so far

```
    <div id="a">
    </div>
```

css

```
#a{

    width: 150px;
    height:200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:7px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;

}


@media screen and (max-width:1500px)(max-height:3000px) {
    #a {
        width: 70%;
        height:70%;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `and`

```
@media screen and (max-width:1500px) and (max-height:3000px) {
```

Why would you use `max-height:3000px`? Think about *mobile-first* than.
Build your CSS starting from *"minimal-or-up"*, in other words simply use something like:

```
/* Default styles +  Extrasmall devices and up!! */
#a{
  width: 70%;
  border: 7px solid #000;
}

/* Tablets and up */
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  #a{
      width: 150px;
      /* 7px border will be inherited from extrasmall devices... etc */
  }
}

/* Desktop and up */
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  #a{
    /* Will be 150px width. Need styles?  */
  }
}

/* Large desktops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
  #a{
    /* Will be 150px width. Need styles?  */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you wrote is almost it, but

1.) use percentage values also in the "regular" CSS. You can combine them with `max-width`, `min-width`, `max-height` and/or `min-height` settings with `px` values in order not to go above or below a certain size.

2.) When using percentage values, the parent element needs to have a set width and/or height (depending on which axis you use the percentage values). And that also applies to the parent of the parent, and so on up to the `body` and `html` elements, which is why you often see this rule:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```